# Android app having pre ICS style

Tags: android

I am developing an Android app and when I run it by default (with no particular styling) it has a pre-ICS look (no holo interface). This is what I have on my style.xml

```
 <style name="Adif" parent="@android:Theme.Light">

    </style>
```

How can I make my app look like Holo when available? I still want to be able to provide support to pre-ICS devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want HOLO style on on all platforms you should use something like lib [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere), otherwise you should create values-v14 folder in which in styles.xml you will extend your app theme from Holo themes:

 `<style name="AppBaseNoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />`

 in default values folder you can leave styles extending them from pre-ICS themes.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make my app look like Holo when available?

```
<style name="Adif" parent="@android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Light"/>
```

Comment: Then separate the style by creating specific res folders like values-v7 values-v13  etc